# Function returning false when called inside another function while individual return type is true

Tags: c++

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

bool isPointWithinSphere(std::vector<int> point, const double &radius) {
  std::transform(point.begin(), point.end(), point.begin(),
                 [](auto &x) { return std::pow(x, 2); });

  return std::sqrt(std::accumulate(point.begin(), point.end(), 0,
                                   std::plus<int>())) <= radius;
}

void print_container(std::vector<int> &vec) {
  for (auto i : vec) std::cout << i << " ";

  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void foo(std::vector<int> &vec, int k, int nest_level) {
  for (int i = -k; i <= k; i++) {
    vec.push_back(i);
    if (vec.size() == nest_level) {
      if (isPointWithinSphere(vec, k)) print_container(vec);
    }
    if (vec.size() != nest_level) foo(vec, k, nest_level);
    vec.pop_back();
  }
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec{};
  std::vector<int> p{1, 0, 1};
  std::cout << isPointWithinSphere(p, 1.5);
  foo(vec, 1.5, 3);
}
```

When I pass in the vector `p {1, 0, 1}` to the function `isPointWithinSphere(p, 1.5)` the result is `true`. Now when my function `foo` generates the vector `{ 1, 0, 1 }` and passes it into `isPointWithinSphere` it returns `false`.

Why is my function giving me two different answers for the same input?

Comment: Are you sure the vector being generated is correct?  Have you stepped through the code to see what is going on?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I printed out all the points generated by the vector, it does indeed generate 1, 0, 1

Comment: temp.cpp:36:12: warning: implicit conversion from 'double' to 'int' changes value from 1.5 to 1 [-Wliteral-conversion]
  foo(vec, 1.5, 3);

Comment: Yes but you aren't passing the same arguments to `isPointInSphere`. You should try using a debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Becasue you are truncating your numbers.

```
std::cout << isPointWithinSphere(p, 1.5);
                                    ^^^   Double.

Calls =>

bool isPointWithinSphere(std::vector<int> point, const double &radius)
                                                       ^^^^^^ Good.
```

BUT:

```
foo(vec, 1.5, 3);
         ^^^^   Double

 Calls =>

 void foo(std::vector<int> &vec, int k, int nest_level) {
                                 ^^^^^^   Ooops
```

The value of k is truncated down to 1 before `foo()` is entered. So when it is later used to call the function `isPointWithinSphere()` it only gets 1.

As pointed out by @Jeremy Friesner in the comments:

> temp.cpp:36:12: warning: implicit conversion from 'double' to 'int' changes value from 1.5 to 1 [-Wliteral-conversion] foo(vec, 1.5, 3);

The compiler will actually tell you about these types of errors. You should ensure that your code will compile with zero warnings at the highest warning level you can stand (this can be done on all modern compilers).

Answer (score 1):

In your foo() function parameter k is an integer so 1.5 will be converted to 1. I`m sure that this conversion is your problem. However, please do your self a favor and do not work with floating point values in a for loop with an comparative operator.